# Использовать строку в качестве метода к переменной python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, методы

У меня есть функция, которая убирает дочерние теги из главного тега

```
def tags_decompose(self, tag, part_tree):
    if tag == 'span':
        part_tree.span.decompose()
    elif tag == 'h1':
        part_tree.h1.decompose()
    ...
```

Переменных `tag` будет гораздо больше.
Есть ли способ использовать строку `tag` в качестве метода для части html разметки `part_tree`?

К примеру у меня есть данная разметка:

```
<span class="nowrap">
    1 051
    <span class="b-item-price__kopeck">20</span>
    <span class="price-currency"> руб.</span>
    <span class="price-unit">/шт</span>
</span>
```

Мне нужно убрать все 3 дочерних тега span

Comment: можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В python есть встроенные функции [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) и [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr), которые могут получать/устанавливать значения атрибутов по имени.

В кокретном случае следующий код должен сработать:

```
getattr(part_tree, tag).decompose()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает